# How to change object's position wrt camera in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to change my object's position with respect to camera position. I mean, my object should always be just in front of the camera. It should follow camera movements.What do I need to add my object drawing function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using old-style fixed function matrices, the easiest way to position an object relative to the camera is to do it *after removing* the camera matrix from the stack. For example, you might have a matrix setup like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(...); //Or other camera functions.
for(/*each object*/)
{
  glPushMatrix();
   //Setup object matrices.
  glTranslatef();
  glRotatef();

  //Setup object rendering.
  glDrawElements(); //Draw the object

  glPopMatrix();
}
```

Then switch it around into this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
gluLookAt(...); //Or other camera functions.
for(/*each object*/)
{
  glPushMatrix();
   //Setup object matrices.
  glTranslatef();
  glRotatef();

  //Setup object rendering.
  glDrawElements(); //Draw the object

  glPopMatrix();
}
glPopMatrix(); //Remove camera matrix. MODELVIEW is now identity.
for(/*each camera-relative object*/)
{
  glPushMatrix();
   //Setup object matrices.
  glTranslatef();
  glRotatef();

  //Setup object rendering.
  glDrawElements(); //Draw the object

  glPopMatrix();
}
```

If you're using shaders, this is even easier. If you have a matrix stack, just do the same stack-based operation as you see here. If you're doing something else to build your matrices, just don't factor the camera matrix into the transform.

Answer (score 1):

Your object position should then always be at:

```
desiredPosition = cameraPosition + cameraDirection * offset;
```

Comment: And what would happen if the "up" direction for the camera is not the same as the up direction for world-space?

Comment: You can always adjust your up to be perpenticular to your front vector

Comment: My point is that "right" should always be perpendicular to up and forward. Your equation doesn't take into account where up is, so if the camera rotates around the view direction, the `desiredPosition` won't take this into account.

Comment: @NicolBolas a position, right in front of the camera (along the `front` vector, moved away at an `offset` length) will always be the same even if you `roll` the camera (change the `up` / `right` vector), therefore `pos + front * scalar` gives you the target position. It's pretty simple, let me know if you need a drawing...